# Brand new Lenovo u410 heats up around touchpad

Tags: lenovo-laptop, overheating

My Lenovo u410 started heating around the right palm rest minutes after I unpacked it!
I am devastated, because I bought this for programming, and it's impossible to type on this for extended periods with the surface getting so hot. I haven't run any serious programs on it yet, so the processor has been pretty much idle.

I've been Googling this problem, and found only one person who had this issue too. Is this is a defect in the product? Why aren't many others getting this problem?

I bought it via newegg.com and as per their policy you can't return a product once you've opened it.

Specs:
Core i5, 6 GB RAM, 750 GB harddisk. Running Windows 8.

Comment: what is the laptop lying on? is that the side your dvd/cdr is on?

Comment: Have u installed all drivers?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The laptop is lying on a flat table surface. There is no DVD/CD drive in this model. As for the drivers, no, I haven't installed them because I assumed that since Windows was pre-installed, so would be the drivers. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's your power scheme? Or simply, check your task manager, what's the CPU speed?

Comment: Newegg will take it back (minus a 15% restocking fee) if you have all the original packaging. You could even insist that it's defective (which it is!) and demand a replacement. Since this item is out of stock, they'd have to offer you something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the NVIDIA Graphics card in the BIOS and check the heat. I did the same and some heat is reduced.

Since I was facing the same issue I contacted the customer care and got the answer that the heat is expected behavior because the graphics card present in that area.

They can not rectify this issue as this is design defect and not willing to refund also.

Comment: I guess we will have to live with it.

Comment: I have noticed that it gets really hot when the battery is charging (i.e., is < 100% while the laptop is plugged in) but settles down to a warm temperature when the battery has been fully charged.

Comment: Hi Karthik! Please register your account here on Super User so you stay logged in.